# How to prevent my firebase service from being killed

Tags: android, service, android-service

Here is my Firebase Service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        sendNotification("a", "b");

    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String text) {
        *notification builder code*
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }
}
```

I want to make him able to receive messages from FCM after app force killed (swiped out from task list). How to implement it?